# Is there a way to reuse a window in teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I would like to reuse the same window definition multiple times within a single query.

Postgres does it this way:

```
SELECT sum(salary) OVER w, avg(salary) OVER w
FROM empsalary
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC);
```

Does teradata have an equivalent function to do this?

Comment: No, it's time for Cut&Paste :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no equivalent of window function in TD, you have to write window every time

```
SELECT sum(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC), avg(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC)
FROM empsalary;
```

Some documents about window functions:

http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/Ordered_Analytical_Functions.083.013.html

http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/Ordered_Analytical_Functions.083.012.html#ww1271958

Comment: That's what I was afraid of... I'd looked through the docs but thought there may be a workaround.